# Django Not Loading All CSS Files

Tags: django, static

I have several CSS files listed in my base.html, and while one of them is loaded, everything else isn't, nor the javascript or images.

The following is a portion of base.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="/media/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>        
    <link href="/media/css/home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="/media/css/slideshow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="/media/css/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    ...
```

with media being the folder in the base directory that contains the static files. When viewing the source of the page produced, `base.css` loads fine, but for everything else, I get `Page not found: [Name of CSS file here]`. As far as I can tell, there isn't any difference between base.css and home.css; the folder location, the file permissions...I just can't figure out why it can find one file and not the rest. Does anyone have any ideas what might be going on?

**Settings.py**

```
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath("")
ROOT_URL = 'http://url that will be used for running product/'


MEDIA_ROOT = ROOT_DIR + 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = ROOT_URL + 'media/'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += patterns('django.views',
        url(r'^media/css/(?P<path>.*)$', 'static.serve',
            {'document_root': ROOT_DIR + 'media/css/'}, name='css-root'),
        (r'^media/images/(?P<path>.*)$', 'static.serve',
            {'document_root': ROOT_DIR + 'media/images/'}),
        (r'^media/scripts/(?P<path>.*)$', 'static.serve',
            {'document_root': ROOT_DIR + 'media/script/'}),
)
```

Comment: What happens when you view those paths in the browser directly? Do you get the files you expect?

Comment: @Daniel - it's just as I said: I can see base.css, but everything else is "Page not found"

Comment: Sorry, didn't read that properly. But - sounds like a strange question, I know - are you actually sure that the `base.css` you are getting is the actual one for your site and not, say, the one for the admin?

Comment: @Daniel - There's a base.css for admin? Now that you mention it, you're right. That's what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so we've got to the bottom of this now. Your `MEDIA_URL` setting is conflicting with the `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` setting - they are both set to `/media', and the admin one takes precedence.

Set `MEDIA_URL` to something else - `/site_media`, for example - and things should be happier.

Answer (score 0):

What is your MEDIA_ROOT set to?  I'm surprised you are having to do more than just "/css/base.css" etc.

Comment: Same thing, but with the prefix of the URL that will be used in production. I'll edit my post with it.